# Can I add more than one business to a Google My Business account?

Tags: google-my-business

I have a Google account, and when I login to Google My Business, I have one business that I can manage. I am looking to add a completely separate business. I'm not looking to add multiple locations/branches of the same business/chain.

Is it possible to add a second, separate business here, that I can manage from the same account?

Or do I have to create a completely separate Google account, attach a separate Google My Business account, and add my new business there?

Comment: You should be able to verify your second business through the same Google Account.

Comment: @AnsonWHan OK thanks.  But how exactly do I add the second business?  Do I click "Add new location" (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/NfnxbPj)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to sign out of your account, go to https://www.google.com/business/ and register with the start now button (as if you were starting from scratch)

Comment: OK. Just to be clear, you're now saying I should create a new Google account, and add this new business to that account--is that correct?  I just want to be clear because it seems like it contradicts your previous suggestion.  Not arguing with you--I just want to be clear.

Comment: Finally got the answer here: https://janac.medium.com/how-to-add-a-second-business-to-google-my-business-profile-f68bc84d94cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and the answer seems to be that I need to create a separate Google account.  Adding a second "location" to my existing Google My Business account should be done if I'm adding a second branch of the same business.  I say that because of the instructions on [this Google page](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?hl=en).  The verbiage is:

*All locations must have the same name unless the business’s real world representation consistently varies from location to location. All locations must also have the same category if they provide the same service.*

That still could be construed as a little vague.  But in my case the second business is not the same category as the first, so I'll take this to mean that I should *not* add it as a second "location."

Comment: I use my one google account for two completely different businesses located on two different addresses. Simply by adding a "new location". From there I can switch to one or the other location, which indeed is not only another "location" but rather another business. With all its adjustments etc.

Comment: Creating a second google account is not necessary whatsoever. See my tutorial here: https://janac.medium.com/how-to-add-a-second-business-to-google-my-business-profile-f68bc84d94cc

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. You can do that. Go to locations, if you want to add location of a completely new business. Google will ask you to verify the business through code sent to your postal address.

Comment: For screenshots on exactly how to do this, see here https://janac.medium.com/how-to-add-a-second-business-to-google-my-business-profile-f68bc84d94cc